# How custom Allure report to create allure results (XML) separatedly after finished a Scenario (cucumber - java)

Tags: java, cucumber, allure

My auto framework use Cucumber + Java + Allure report. I am facing a problem when Company electrics is interrupted (or stop runnẻ suddenly) the allure result of running FEATURE is NOT generated. Because Allure results (xml file) is only generated after finished whole feature file.

Now I am looking for a way to force Allure report generate XML result after finished a scenario. Sorry about my english is not good

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by re-write class AllureReporter (https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-cucumberjvm/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/allure/cucumberjvm/AllureReporter.java). Fire TestSuiteFinishedEvent after testcaseFinished

```
@Override
public void endOfScenarioLifeCycle(Scenario scenario) {
    synchronized (gherkinSteps) {
        while (gherkinSteps.peek() != null) {
            fireCanceledStep(gherkinSteps.remove());
        }
    }
    ALLURE_LIFECYCLE.fire(new TestCaseFinishedEvent());
    ALLURE_LIFECYCLE.fire(new TestSuiteFinishedEvent(uid));
}
```